# Uncaught runtime errors: ERROR Failed to fetch TypeError: Failed to fetch

Tags: javascript, reactjs, json, redux, react-redux

Getting this error while fetching the data from json file.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dTJHs.jpg)

```
export function fetchAllProducts() { return new Promise(async (resolve) =>{

//TODO: we will not hard-code server URL here

const response = await fetch('http://localhost:8080/products') const data = await response.json()

resolve({data})

}

);

}
```

Comment: Is backend server running? Do you have any errors on backend? What was the response status code? Include some more info in the question